# Switch language programmatically on an Android device

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I'm writing some Android test automation for our applications, which are localized into 18 languages.

I need the ability to switch the language on the device programmatically - I don't mean to switch the language of just the application - I mean switch the actual device language in the Android settings, that way our application switches also.

Is there any way I can accomplish this via MonkeyRunner, the Android Debug Bridge or otherwise? Ideally I'd like a way that works on both the android emulator, and a physical device.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured out you can do this via the [Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) which I've just installed on my test machine and added to the windows PATH variable.

For example, the command to switch the device language to German would be:

```
adb shell "su -c 'setprop persist.sys.language de; setprop persist.sys.country de; stop; sleep 5; start'
```

*You will need a rooted device in order for this to work.*

Answer (score 1):

You can change the local like this :

```
   Resources res = context.getResources();
    // Change locale settings in the app.
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = new Locale(language_code.toLowerCase());
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

Comment: Is this setting the locale from the mobile applications code? If so, I don't think you read my question correctly - I need to switch the device language, from an automation application independent from my mobile applications code.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script, which sends a broadcast to a helper app like [adb send broadcast](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#IntentSpec) and this app changes your configuration inside the device like device language where you can use that code of @iSun.